# Whitelisting network access for a specific program in Windows

Tags: windows-7, networking, security, windows-firewall, tor

I'm normally a Linux user, but in a while I'll need to use a Windows 7 system for a bit (not something I look forward to). I am using Tor Browser for anonymity. On Linux, I can use Netfilter to restrict network access to Tor Browser. Specifically, I run the Tor process as a daemon and give its user full internet access, but I block the browser from connecting to anything but 127.0.0.1:9050, the local Tor SOCKS application port. How do I do this on Windows 7 using its built-in firewall application?

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at Windows firewall and it seems you can do this with the following.

- Create a new rule for a program.
- Select the .exe of the program you want to filter.
- Select whatever you need for the rule creation.
- Once it's created modify it and go on the "extended" tab.
- Here you can select the IPs the program is allowed to communicate with. Click add and type 127.0.0.1
- Then go on "protocols and ports" tab and select the ports the same way.

Hope it helps

Edit: formating